# Error when writing a function that pushes a unique pointer into a vector

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes in a unique pointer as a parameter and pushes it into a function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class SomeObject
{

};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> someObjects;

void PushSomeObject(const std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject)
{
    someObjects.push_back(pSomeObject);
}

SomeObject* Create()
{
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
    PushSomeObject(pSomeObject);
    return someObjects.back().get();
}

int main()
{
    SomeObject* pSomeObject = Create();
}
```

But I am getting an error

```
 error: use of deleted function
```

in line

```
PushSomeObject(pSomeObject);
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to copy a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I am creating it in a local scope, so I kinda have no choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying a unique ptr twice.  Unique ptrs cannot be copied, as each unique ptr claims exclusive ownership over the lifetime of the pointed to resource.

```
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
    PushSomeObject(std::move(pSomeObject));
```

this fixes the first copy.

'
The second cooy requires two fixes.

```
void PushSomeObject(std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject)
```

I removed `const` here.  Moving from a unique ptr modifies the pointer, if not  the pointed to.

```
someObjects.push_back(std::move(pSomeObject));
```

I added move here.

Move states that you don't mind destructive ooeratiins be used to transfer the state out of the variable, which in turn makes use after move errors more obvious.  You can move ownership of the pointed to resource from a unique ptr to another unique ptr, just not copy it.

Comment: Do you recon using a shared pointer would be better for what I am trying to do ?

Comment: @cool I do not know what you are trying to do, but I rarely recommend shared pointers for mutable state.  They make managing extremely complex lifetime rules easier, but extremely complex lifetime rules are usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The type of smart pointer you use is a promise to the users of your code.

```
void PushSomeObject(const std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject) {
  someObjects.push_back(pSomeObject);
}
```

This says "this function requires total *unique* ownership of the object to work", which is not true and far too strict, as you've just discovered.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
PushSomeObject(pSomeObject);
return someObjects.back().get();
```

Here, we start with a `pSomeObject`. It's a unique pointer, so only one function can have ownership over it. The first thing we do is try to copy the value and pass it to `PushSomeObject`, which violates `unique_ptr`'s rules. We *could* move it

```
// DO NOT RUN THIS CODE
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
PushSomeObject(std::move(pSomeObject));
return someObjects.back().get();
```

You won't get a compile error. But this is still dead wrong. The first thing we do is *move* ownership to `PushSomeObject`. Now we don't own the value anymore. It's gone. Then we try to take this value we don't own and return something from it. That'd be like if I gave you bag full of money, then you went home; later that day, I try to pay for groceries by reaching into the bag of money that I don't have anymore.

That's why the code doesn't work right now. So how do we fix it? Well, your function contract is too strong. If you don't intend to take ownership, you need to use a reference.

```
void PushSomeObject(SomeObject& pSomeObject) {
  someObjects.push_back(pSomeObject);
}
```

Now we can call it by *borrowing* the value.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> pSomeObject = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
PushSomeObject(*pSomeObject);
return someObjects.back().get();
```

We never lose ownership of our value. We make it, we let someone else *borrow* it (but we retain ownership), and then we return some information from it. `std::unique_ptr` is happy, because there's only ever one owner.

Comment: You misread; `someObjects` is a vector of unique ptrs, and `someObjects.back().get();` does not read or attempt to from `pSomeObject`

Comment: @Silvio This gives an error `no instance of overloaded function...matches the argument list`. Its on line `someObjects.push_back(pSomeObject);`